# Decision Trees - Regression trees weighting of child nodes?

Tags: cart

I'm familiar with how classification trees weight the impurity measure of a potential split by the proportion of observations that would fall into each child node, such as:

$$
loss = \frac{n_1}{N_m} G_1 + \frac{n_2}{N_m} G_2
$$

where:

- $N_m$ is the number of observations in node $m$ (i.e. the parent node
  that will be split).
- $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the number of observations in the "left" and
  "right" daughter nodes that will result from the split, respectively.
- $G_1$ and $G_2$ are the impurity measures of the "left" and "right"
  daughter nodes, respectively (either Gini Impurity or Cross-Entropy).

I'm a little confused on whether this weighting applies to the regression setting as well. In the [Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf) (page 308) the splitting mechanism for a regression oriented decision tree is defined in equation (9.13), reproduced below:

$$
min \left( min \left[ \sum_{x_i \in R_{m1}}^n (y_i - c_{m1})^2 \right] + min \left[ \sum_{x_i \in R_{m2}}^n (y_i - c_{m2})^2 \right] \right)
$$

where

$$
c_m = \frac{\sum_{i \in R_m}^n y_i }{\left| R_m \right|}
$$

However, on page (309 - 310), the authors mention that, "For regression we used the squared-error node impurity measure defined in **(9.15)**," which seems to imply that the squared error metric **is** weighted by the proportion of observations that fall into each child node due to a binary split.

So, the overall question is: Does the weighting of the child nodes apply in both the regression and classification setting, or only the classification setting?

Comment: This is a good read on this topic: https://www.benkuhn.net/tree-imp